# Inject variable into regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, url, match

So I am trying to certain values from a URL. Suppose I have the following URL:

```
let url = "https://gk.example.com/my-path/to/some+more/multiple.variables/moreparams";
```

I am trying to extract the `some+more` and `multiple.variables` parts from the URL using a Regular Expression. I came up with the following expressions:

`/(?<=/)([^/]*\+[^/]*)(?=/)/g` (for the `+` separator) and `/(?<=/)([^/]*\.[^/]*)(?=/)/g` (for the `.` separator)

```
results = url.match(/(?<=/)([^/]*\+[^/]*)(?=/)/g); // result: ['some+more']
results = url.match(/(?<=/)([^/]*\.[^/]*)(?=/)/g); // result: ['gk.example.com', 'multiple.variables']
```

This returns `['some+more']` and `['gk.example.com', 'multiple.variables']`, which is a result I can work with. However, instead of using a if statement to switch between expressions, I would rather inject a variable into a generic regular expression. I tried the following (using backticks ( ` ) to be able to inject the variable :

```
function getSplitUrl(sep, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    let regex = new RegExp('(?<=/)([^/]*'+sep+'[^/]*)(?=/)', `g`),
        results = [];
    results[0] = url.match(`(?<=/)([^/]*${sep}[^/]*)(?=/)`, `g`);
    results[1] = regex.exec(url);
    console.log('Regex 1: ', regex); // logs `Regex 1: /(?<=/)([^/]*${sep}[^/]*)(?=\/)/g`, where ${sep} is replaced by either \. or \+ (seemingly correct expression)
    console.log(url, sep, results);
    return null;
}
```

From the `console.log(regex)` it seems that it is the correct regular expression but the result is still wrong. The result is now `['gk.example.com', 'gk.example.com']`.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Edit:

Somehow, `url.match(regex)` returns a correct result, whereas `regex.exec(url)` does not.

Comment: You did not escape *all* the backslashes (although in fact when using `RegExp`, you don't need to escape `/`, so this doesn't matter), you did not escape the separator, and in `url.match(…)` you forgot to call `new RegExp`

Comment: Indeed, I always escape `/` in regex but it was not neccessary... Updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple and don't use regex, but rather [the `URL` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to parse urls:

```js
const url = new URL("https://gk.example.com/my-path/to/some+more/multiple.variables/moreparams?limit=5&more=conf/fusion");
console.log(url.hostname);
console.log(url.pathname)
const parts = url.pathname.slice(1).split('/');
console.log(parts);
const find = (substring) => parts.filter(p => p.includes(substring));
console.log(find('+'));
console.log(find('.'));
```

Comment: I like this solution. It is nice and clean and I will definitely use this instead of the regex. However, I would still like to know why my regex is not working properly so I can take that info with me for future purposes.